# Merge two array and if some value true add property? Javascript

Tags: javascript

I need loop thought two array and return another array with different values.

Example of two arrays:

```
let arr1 = ['one' , 'two' , 'three'];
let arr2 = ['four' , 'one' , 'two'];
```

What do I need?

Loop thought both array and return the same value, I expect new array like:

```
let res = [
 { name : 'one' , isSame: true },
 { name : 'two' , isSame: true },
 { name : 'three' },
 { name : 'four' }
];
```

I am removed the duplicate items and add `isSame` value to true on duplicated values.

One and two are duplicated ( twice ).

What I have tried

```
 let arr3 = arr1.map((item, i) =>
 Object.assign({}, item, arr2[i])
 );
```

But I got a splitted array and it's removed duplicated

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to use `reduce()` to do it

```js
let arr1 = ['one' , 'two' , 'three'];
let arr2 = ['four' , 'one' , 'two'];

let arr3 = arr1.concat(arr2)
let result = arr3.reduce((a,c) =>{
  let obj = a.find(i => i.name == c)
  if(obj){
    obj['isSame'] = true
   }else{
     a.push({'name':c})
   }
  return a
},[])
console.log(result)
```

---

Update:
solution without `reduce()`,using `set()` to remove duplicate elements,and using `includes()` to find duplicate elements

### ```js
let arr1 = ['one' , 'two' , 'three'];
let arr2 = ['four' , 'one' , 'two'];

let arr3 = [...new Set(arr1.concat(arr2))]
let result = arr3.map(a =>{
  let data = {'name':a}
  if(arr1.includes(a) && arr2.includes(a)){
    data["isSame"] = true
  }
  return data
})
console.log(result)
```

Update: Based on OP's comments,show with opposite result

```js
let arr1 = ['one' , 'two' , 'three'];
let arr2 = ['four' , 'one' , 'two'];

let arr3 = [...new Set(arr1.concat(arr2))]
let result = arr3.map(a =>{
  let data = {'name':a}
  if(!arr1.includes(a) || !arr2.includes(a)){
    data["isSame"] = true
  }
  return data
})
console.log(result)
```

Comment: I try to avoid reduce... I need solution without reduce

Comment: I need opposite of this. 

example if if(!arr1.includes(a) && !arr2.includes(a)) ... i try self but without success.

Comment: Right now is opposite where i need to set isSame

Comment: @sisihop96 you need to use `if(!arr1.includes(a) || !arr2.includes(a))` instead,in this case `isSame` is `false`

Comment: I need to add opposite. like if(!arr1.includes(a) || !arr2.includes(a)) isSame = true

Comment: In this situation, i add isSame true to the wrong items. The opposite

Comment: @sisihop96 Can you check it again,please,for the third code snippet

Answer (score 2):

[Reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to an intermediate object and then [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) that object's [entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries):

```js
const arr1 = ['one' , 'two' , 'three'];
const arr2 = ['four' , 'one' , 'two'];

const result = Object.entries([...arr1, ...arr2].reduce(
  (a, v) => ({ ...a, [v]: v in a }),
  {}
)).map(([name, isSame]) => ({ name, isSame }));

console.log(result);
```

The spreading behavior in the `reduce()` callback increases time complexity in favor of being more terse, but can easily be avoided, making this solution `O(n)`:

```js
const arr1 = ['one' , 'two' , 'three'];
const arr2 = ['four' , 'one' , 'two'];

const result = Object.entries([...arr1, ...arr2].reduce(
  (a, v) => {
    a[v] = v in a;
    return a;
  },
  {}
)).map(([name, isSame]) => ({ name, isSame }));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't want reduce, you can loop through each item, and check the next few values.

This is natively faster with less function calls, just two for loops.

```js
let arr1 = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
let arr2 = ['four', 'one', 'two'];

console.log(merge(arr1, arr2));

function merge(a, b) {
  const merged = a.concat(b); // combine arrays
  const result = [];
  
  let stop = merged.length; // create a variable for when to stop
  for(let i = 0; i < stop; i++) {
    const current = merged[i];
    let same = false;
    
    // look through the rest of the array for indexes
    for(let t = i + 1; t < stop; t++) {
      if(current === merged[t]) {
        same = true;
        merged.splice(t, 1); // remove duplicate elements from the array so we don't come across it again
        stop--; // we've removed an element from the array, so we have to stop 1 earlier
        // we don't break this loop because there may be more than 2 occurences
      }
    }
    const out = { name: current };
    if(same) out.isSame = true;
    
    result.push(out);
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: *"This is natively faster with less function calls, just two for loops."* Sounds good on the face of it, but you're nesting your loops which gives you a time complexity of `O(n^2)`. You could argue that for the average case it's `O(n log n)`, but other solutions have `O(n)` for the worst case.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen look carefully. The time complexity is _not_ `O(n^2)`. The starting index of the nested loop is the current index + 1. This actually executes the same way the other answers do, but more verbose and without the built in looping methods (`Array#reduce` and `isThisKey in thisObject` both require some degree of looping).

Comment: An object lookup `key in object` has a time complexity of `O(1)`, and `reduce()` is `O(n)`.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen I hate to spring an argument, but I believe what really matters is the speed at which it executes, so I created benchmarks. On my device I ran the top answer's solution against mine 100,000 times each, with the other solution at 95ms while mine being 45ms. Why don't you try it?

Comment: A benchmark with n = 6 does not constitute a benchmark at all, no matter how many times you run it. Why don't you try with a couple of thousand near-unique elements and report back.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen it is until now that I realized that there is only a chance of a single duplicate, and that it will be in different arrays (I assumed that both arrays were equally random and that there was an infinite amount of duplicates in either array). I will revise my answer to match the question, but given that it would obviously be faster for an answer built that way.

Answer (score 0):

- I have used `map()` function of array.
- `map()` returns new array by performing code logic on each valid entry.
- `[...new Set([...arr1, ...arr2])]`, this will return new array with unique values.
- I am assuming, that you are checking if value is in both array or not and based upon that we are returning object.

```js
let arr1 = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
let arr2 = ['four', 'one', 'two'];
let mergedArray = [...new Set([...arr1, ...arr2])];
let result = mergedArray.map(value => {
  if (arr1.includes(value) && arr2.includes(value)) {
    return {
      value,
      isInBothArray: true
    }
  } else {
    return {
      value,
      isInBothArray: false
    }
  }
});
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const arr1 = ['one' , 'two' , 'three'];
const arr2 = ['four' , 'one' , 'two'];
// returns the duplicate values in the two arrays
const findDuplicates = (arr) => {
  let sorted_arr = arr.slice().sort();
  let results = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < sorted_arr.length - 1; i++) {
    if (sorted_arr[i + 1] == sorted_arr[i]) {
      results.push(sorted_arr[i]);
    }
  }
  return results;
}

let values = ([...new Set([...arr1, ...arr2])]);
let duplicates = findDuplicates(values);

let retval = [];

for(let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
  let isSame = duplicates.includes(values[i]);
  retval.push({name: values[i], isSame: isSame})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const arr1 = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
const arr2 = ['four', 'one', 'two'];

const result = Array.from(new Set(arr1.concat(arr2))).reduce((p, c) => {
    const obj = { name: c };
    if (arr1.concat(arr2).join("").split(c).length - 1 > 1) obj.isSame = true;
    p.push(obj)
    return p;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```